# How to avoid form-control in all inputs with Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a website with a framework in which the HTML is automatically generated. Twitter Bootstrap 3 needs the class "form-control" added to each input to properly apply the width to such inputs. Problem is that to add that css class from code, I would need to change the framework in many places.

Is there a work around? Maybe some javascript/jquery that searches all labels in my form, for each label it finds the associated input and finally add the css class? But I really don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit `forms.less` and recompile the css, but it could be tricky because you don't want all inputs or text areas to have that `.form-control` styling.

If you have an ID for your form that you want to apply it to, this should help:

```
$('#yourFormId input, #yourFormId textarea, #yourFormId input, #yourFormId select').addClass('form-control');
```

You would need to make sure you are adding all the form field types that are in your form, but that above line would probably cover most of them.  This is pretty hacky though, depending on your framework there may be some sort of mixin or function to include class names in auto generated forms.

Comment: Thanks. This was the easiest solution for me. I needed to exclude buttons, submit and checkbox from inputs, but the rest is right. It took this solution because the framework I am using is not easy to extend from this regard.

Comment: I'm starting to do this with jquery also, but I'm wondering if it is "bad practice"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea because it is a "hacky" implementation of bootstrap. Not only do you need the classes you need the proper html structure. The amount of time trying to craft some magic javascript to implement these two changes would be better spent modifying the framework.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too. Ok, forget the javascript solution. There is no workaround from Bootstrap itself? I have no problem to add divs surrounding the inputs, or the labels. I can easily add css to labels etc. The only complicated part is to add css to inputs.

Comment: @MarianoMartinezPeck There is always a work around but you will have to make something yourself as there is nothing out of the box that would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use Bootstrap's `Less` classes instead of the compiled library and somehow add the necessary tags in your code.

Take a look at this [article](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html).

Answer (score 0):

I've not faced this specific problem, but in general when working with Bootstrap 3 I'll build the .less files myself with my own specific changes, e.g. in my .less file:

```
/* Import the Bootstrap 3 .less files */
@import url('../../Bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less');

/* Now implement my own styling below */
```

Working with .less, you might be able to pull in the relevant styles from the relevant part of the framework, something like this (where .mydiv is your container element) :

```
.mydiv {
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
        .form-control;
    }
}
```

This would pull in the .form-control styles and apply them to input, select and textarea elements inside .mydiv. I've not tried this, but it's worth a try!

Comment: Thanks. I should have said that the framework I use, already uses Bootstrap css so I think that using LESS would be a bit complicated. But thanks for the idea. There is no way to do this with css, right?

Comment: You could go in and manually copy all of their `.form-control` selectors and styles to match your needs. But if the framework already uses Bootstrap (which is itself built using Less) then you could definitely use Bootstrap's less files as long as you only augment them. Honestly though, fixing the framework itself seems like your best option.